# Insert same entity three times from one form

Tags: forms, symfony4

I'm using symfony4 and In my project I have and entity Bill and it offer two packs:

**1)** First pack, user can generate **just one** bill in PDF after filling out a form and saving data in database and it has its own price.

**2)** Second pack, user can generate **Three** bills in PDF after filling out a form and saving data in database and this has its own price also.

The first pack is simple and it works fine , I have created BillType and an action in the controller and everything is well.

```
public function newBillFirstPack(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Bill();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(BillType::class, $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
            //...............
        }
    }
    return $this->render('frontOffice/bill/new_first_pack.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

The problem is with the second pack , I'd like to know how **can I create three bills** from one form. I tried to create 3 FormType 
- FirstBillType and a twig to render its view.
- SecondtBillType and a twig to render its view.
- ThirdBillType and a twig to render its view also.

And in the controller I created three forms.

I didn't test it yet but even it works I don't like it , I fell it's not a clean solution. Imagine if a day I want to edit an attribute in the formType, so I must edit it in three formsType and three html.twig views, same thing if I want to remove or add an attribute in the forms.

I have see in the documentation "How to Embed a Collection of Forms", but that example is how to embed one attribute many times.

Any good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need. New action can handle this and depending on your needs form can run different action.

```
public function newBillThirdPack(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Bill();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(BillType::class, $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->persist(clone $entity);
            $em->persist(clone $entity);
            $em->flush();
            //...............
        }
    }
    return $this->render('frontOffice/bill/new_third_pack.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```